# PHP - uploading images from dynamic form - file naming issue

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I'm building a dynamic form that allows a user to create a variable number of rows per entry.  The form includes an image upload feature. I'm able to get the image upload to work, but not exactly as I would like - the issue is that I seem to be forced to use the 'tmp_name' of the file, and can't get the original file name.

First off, here's my PHP (heading to MySQL)...

```
require '../credentials.php';
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "dynamic_test";
$target_dir = "uploads/";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = '';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$route = $_POST['route'];

$site_array = $_POST['site'];

foreach($site_array as $siteNumber => $value){

    $species_array[$siteNumber] = $_POST['species'.$siteNumber.''];
    $deadinjured_array[$siteNumber] = $_POST['deadinjured'.$siteNumber.''];
    $image_array[$siteNumber] = $_FILES['image'.$siteNumber.'']['tmp_name'];

    foreach($species_array[$siteNumber] as $key => $species){

        if($image_array[$siteNumber][$key]){
            $target_file = ($target_dir . rand(1, 9999999) . strtolower(basename($image_array[$siteNumber][$key])));

            if(move_uploaded_file($image_array[$siteNumber][$key], $target_file)){
                $image_url = $target_file;
            } 
        };        

    $deadinjured = $deadinjured_array[$siteNumber][$key];

    $sql .= "INSERT INTO test (volunteer, route, site, species, deadinjured, image_url)
    VALUES ('$name', '$route', '$siteNumber', '$species', '$deadinjured', '$image_url');";

    };
};


if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "MySQL thanks you";
    $conn->close();
};
```

Notice this line -

```
$image_array[$siteNumber] = $_FILES['image'.$siteNumber.'']['tmp_name'];
```

In order to get the images into $image_array, they required either the ['name'] or ['tmp_name'] suffix - using ['name'] here would cause the `move_uploaded_file` function to fail, though - this generates the error `Undefined variable: image_url`.  However, I found that by building the ['tmp_name'] into the $image_array variable instead, I was able to get the `move_uploaded_file` function to work, since that function is expecting the ['tmp_name'] suffix in the first parameter.

So my question is this - is there a way to get the images into the image array using the actual file name, rather than the temporary name?  This isn't a big deal - the code above does work and I don't need to preserve the actual file names for this particular project - but I'd still like to know the right way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem here was in the syntax. Eihwaz made some good suggestions, but here is the final piece of working code - see my notes for what has changed... (SQL injection threats neutralized)

```
require '../credentials.php';
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "dynamic_test";
$target_dir = "uploads/";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = '';

$name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$route = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['route']);

$site_array = $_POST['site'];

foreach($site_array as $siteNumber => $value){

    $siteNumber = $conn->real_escape_string($siteNumber);

    $species_array[$siteNumber] = $_POST['species'.$siteNumber.''];
    $deadinjured_array[$siteNumber] = $_POST['deadinjured'.$siteNumber.''];

    //IT IS NECESSARY TO SUFFIX THIS WITH ['name'], 
    $image_array[$siteNumber] = $_FILES['image'.$siteNumber.'']['name'];

    foreach($species_array[$siteNumber] as $key => $species){

        if($image_array[$siteNumber][$key]){
            $target_file = ($target_dir . rand(1, 9999999) . strtolower(basename($image_array[$siteNumber][$key])));

            //ALTHOUGH SLIGHTLY LESS ELEGANT THAN USING A VARIABLE, I FOUND THAT THIS WORKED BECAUSE ['tmp_name'] MUST PRECEDE [$key] - I WAS THINKING IT HAD TO BE THE OTHER WAY AROUND
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image'.$siteNumber.'']['tmp_name'][$key], $target_file)){
                $image_url = $conn->real_escape_string($target_file);
            } 
        };        

    $deadinjured = $deadinjured_array[$siteNumber][$key];

    $sql .= "INSERT INTO test (volunteer, route, site, species, deadinjured, image_url)
VALUES ('$name', '$route', '$siteNumber', '$species', '$deadinjured', '$image_url');";

    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store the whole _FILE in your array:

```
require '../credentials.php';
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "dynamic_test";
$target_dir = "uploads/";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = '';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$route = $_POST['route'];

$site_array = $_POST['site'];

foreach($site_array as $siteNumber => $value){

    $species_array[$siteNumber] = $_POST['species'.$siteNumber];
    $deadinjured_array[$siteNumber] = $_POST['deadinjured'.$siteNumber];
    $image_array[$siteNumber] = $_FILES['image'.$siteNumber];

    foreach ($species_array[$siteNumber] as $key => $species) {
        $image_url = false;

        if (isset($image_array[$siteNumber][$key])) {
            $target_file = ($target_dir . $image_array[$siteNumber][$key]['name']);

            if (move_uploaded_file($image_array[$siteNumber][$key]['tmp_name'], $target_file)) {
                $image_url = $target_file;
            } 
        }       

        $deadinjured = isset($deadinjured_array[$siteNumber][$key]) ? $deadinjured_array[$siteNumber][$key] : false;

        $sql .= "INSERT INTO test (volunteer, route, site, species, deadinjured, image_url)
        VALUES ('$name', '$route', '$siteNumber', '$species', '$deadinjured', '$image_url');";

    };
};
```

Notice though, that you have SQL Injection threats. Also, I'd recommend storing the file with a unique name. If you really need to keep the original name, store the original name in the database, along with the auto generated name. So your user will see the file name as he uploaded it, but it will actually be stored on the server with a different name. Use [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) or something similar to generate random names.

Comment: This is returning a few errors - `Undefined offset: 1 ` and `Undefined variable: image_url`.

Comment: And yes, worth noting that this is still in development so there's no validation or SQL injection prevention built in yet.  Just working on getting the flow down...